# How to fix Menu not centered in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, center

- Please help i can't make my menu to centered in my website is menu always right
- I use new page for home page setting and that error
- Is center by i use homepage default setting but that page i can't edit
  website :
  http://k17tcth11.beget.tech
  sorry for my english

This is for Wordpress

```
<nav class="awemenu-nav awemenu-has-logo <?php print $is_transparent_mode ? 'awe-header--transparent' : ''; ?>" data-sticky="<?php echo esc_attr( (bool) mojado_option( 'mojado_header_nav_sticky' ) ); ?>">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="awemenu-container">
                    <div class="awemenu-language-search awe-fr">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header-search' ); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header-language' ); ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php if ( $is_transparent_mode ) : ?>
                        <?php print mojado_site_logo( 'home_logo', true, '<div class="home-logo">', '</div>' ); // WPCS: XSS OK. ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php
                    /**
                     * Navigation Main Menu.
                     */
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'container'      => '',
                        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                        'menu_class'     => 'main-navigation awemenu',
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                        'walker'         => new Mojado_Walker_Menu,
                        'fallback_cb'    => array( 'Mojado_Menu_Support', 'fallback' ),
                    ) );
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .awemenu-container -->

            </div><!-- .container -->
        </nav><!-- .awemenu-nav -->
```

Answer (score 1):

In header.scss line no 8 replace with my CSS. This is going to fixed your problem.

```
.awe-header--transparent.awemenu-standard:not(.awemenu-sticky) {
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 0px;
}
```